# What are Semi-Visible Jets?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, dark-matter, large-hadron-collider

I'm working on a project that aims to discriminate [semi-visible jets](https://www.scipost.org/SciPostPhys.10.4.084/pdf) (SVJs) in a QCD background, through learning from simulated data in the context of the LHC. I know that these are related to [hidden valley models](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0604261), and probably also to dark matter.

Can someone provide an intuitive explanation (even with some technicality) of why SVJs are important, and how these are originated? Also providing some insights about dark sectors, and potential implications for the discovery of dark matter.

(sorry if I'm using an improper language, but I'm not a physicist.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semi-visible jets are particle jets that have some component of mass/energy that is not visible to the detector they are found in. Not visible in this sense means that those components of the jet do not decay into particles that we can observe with current equipment, meaning these could point to new physics.

In terms of the dark sector connection, we assume that with the energies produced at the Large Hadron Collider, for example, we should be able to replicate the particle creation at the Big Bang, meaning that all particles are able to be formed at the energies we have. This includes Dark Matter, which we know must exist from astronomical observations. If dark matter is a particle, then, it should be being produced at the LHC, and as a result there should be jets with those particles in them.

If only a fraction of dark particles produced decay into stable standard model particles, then there will be a component of the jet that is not visible as not all those dark particles will have decayed. We cannot directly detect dark matter at the LHC, so the jet stays semi-visible.
If semi-visible jets are found and the missing components have mass/energy close to observations of dark matter masses, then we have a possible indication of dark matter.

The dark sector itself is connected to the standard model though some mediator particle which itself can decay into dark matter or standard model particles. That is essentially what we look for in those searches at detectors like ATLAS.

Comment: A very clear answer, thank you!